# Openfeint posting scores issue in android

Tags: android, openfeint

I have used the sdk provided on openfenit site, everything is ok, but after lauching when i try to enter the submenu it doesnt work for example leadership boards etc. Plus i am getting an strange error in console that offline settings not found.
 [image] [image]
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you might want to try some of the other options out there for your leaderboards.  Take a look at Swarm (http://swarmconnect.com), Papaya (www.papayamobile.com), or Scoreloop (www.scoreloop.com).